# Passing PHP variables with spaces to bash

Tags: php, bash

I understand this has been answered before, however there's a weird bug in the code.

Here is the bash code which gets the $title variable from the PHP script:

```
#!/bin/bash
url=$1
type=$2
bitrate=$3
vidid=$4
title=$TITLE

TMP_FILE="youtube-mp3-$RANDOM.tmp"

youtube-dl --get-title --get-url --get-filename "$url" > $TMP_FILE 2> "/tmp/$TMP_FILE.err"

exec 42< $TMP_FILE

while read video_title <&42 ; do
  read video_url <&42
  read video_filename <&42
  if [ "$type" = "vorbis" ]; then
    #youtube-dl -x --prefer-ffmpeg --audio-format vorbis --audio-quality "$bitrate" "$url"
    echo "$title" > title-test
  else
    #youtube-dl -x --prefer-ffmpeg --audio-format "$type" --audio-quality "$bitrate" "$url"
    echo "$title" > title-test
  fi
done

exec 42<&-
rm -f $TMP_FILE
```

And here is the PHP code that sends the variable to bash:

```
$link = $cmd;
$video_id = explode("?v=", $link);
$video_id = $video_id[1];
$yturl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id;

$page = file_get_contents($yturl);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);

$title_div = $doc->getElementById('eow-title');
$title = $title_div->nodeValue;
putenv("TITLE=$title");
```

It does correctly echo the YouTube video title to "title-test", however when it does it sends it like:
{enter}{space}{space}{space}{space}$title

So there's blank spaces before the video title, which doesn't correctly work when I attempt to mv, rm or cp the $title variable in bash, and I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at an example: The element having id="eow-title" in the document at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTXN5nOstRs looks like this:

```
  <span id="eow-title" class="watch-title " dir="ltr" title="Richard Dawkins exploding at bullshit in the Bible">
    Richard Dawkins exploding at bullshit in the Bible
  </span>
```

And since there's nothing telling libxml that leading/trailing whitespaces are irrelevant, the node value of that element is "{enter}{space}{space}{space}{space}Richard Dawkins...".

You might get rid of the whitespaces e.g. via [trim()](http://docs.php.net/trim).